# Parse text input before populating table in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django, and trying to build a social networking site to demo a research idea.

I need to get an annotated text input (like a status update) from the user, parse it, and then store the annotations in my SQLite database. (Later, the resulting newsfeed will be filtered based on annotations.) What is the best approach to do this?

- Do I need to use forms?
- Could I build on top of a Django library, microblogging for example, and parse the short annotated message, or 'tweet', to populate my tables?
- Would it help to import 'Feed' and 'markdown' ? This is based on this link : http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Install_Django_and_Build_Your_First_App

So far, a new app has been created, and added to the list of installed apps. I have models created, and can enter data into my tables using admin.

I do have a lot of social network related apps pre-installed in the Pinax project that I started out with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what I've guessed from your question is that you want the your models to have the capability of parsing the input text. If so you can overload the default constructor of your model. Search for overloading the default constructor of the model. If you don't want to do that then you can parse your input in the your views and then save it to your model. 
If I've not answered your question then may be you can try elaborating it a bit..

Comment: Parsing input in views should serve the purpose. I will search around and come back to elaborate if it doesn't work. Thank you!